# What kind of web hosting is this anyway? (DNS/CNAME)

Tags: web-hosting

I like to have my domains registered via the same company so when I'm looking for a web host I have a very specific requirement -- that I just need space to upload stuff that I can direct to via my registar's DNS/CNAME settings. I don't need a 'free' domain name, or email, or to transer my existing registrations. Just space and the config info to send traffic to it.

So I'm shopping around for a new host at the moment and was wondering if there's a shorthand term for what I'm after, because it seems like it would be a fairly regular requirement and there'd be a term for it.

So that's my question, really. What's the most succunct way to articulate the kind of hosting I require to prospective hosts? (All suggestions for good, *affordable* hosts who do this sort of thing gratefully received of course!)

Comment: www.Bluehost.com
www.Dreamhost.com
ww.1and1.com

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting companies do this for you. I believe what you are asking for is the term **VirtualHost**